# Will Android WebView be automatically updated?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

According to Google's doc (https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview)

> The WebView will auto-update for mobile devices with Android L and above.

But I'm wondering will WebView still be auto updated even if I turn off the auto-update option in Play Store?

Comment: add some reference to the above statement so that we can read there and clear understanding about the same

Answer (score 0):

this webview is going to be seperate apk,
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview&hl=en_SG&gl=US

so it will not update if autoupdate is disabled.